# Moving 2007 C++Builder SOAP code with certificate handling to Delphi2018-Indy10

Tags: delphi, c++builder, indy10, gsoap

I have a .dll written in C++/Builder of 2007, that uses GSOAP for it's connections to a webservice, It seems to require the location of a .PEM file and it's password (This file is created form a .pfx file delivered by the service organization to authenticate and encrypt). Besides gsoap, it uses openSSL version 0.9.8

Now I need to update SSL to TLS1.2, and this is not covered with openSSL 0.9.8, and updating to version 1.0.2 (the latest I could use) is impossible, because I get a bunch of errors in the OpenSSL code on compilation.

Translation to Delphi 2007 did not really help - since Indy lacks required facilities as well (SOAP1.2 is not supported, it seems) .

However, moving to Ddelphi2018 is on my TODO list so I moved the code for this process to a standalone program (for now) to Delphi. All seems well except for one thing:

in gsoap file stdsoap2.h, there is:

```
struct SOAP_STD_API soap
…
  unsigned short ssl_flags;
  const char *keyfile;
  const char *password;
…
```

and the C++ code uses this

```
  struct soap soap;
  memset(&soap, 0, sizeof(soap));
  ...
  soap.keyfile = Parms->pCERTIFICAAT;    // is .pem bestand, including path
  soap.password = "(Certww)";            // hardcoded in deze code....
  ...
```

However, In Delphi/Indy I don't see any way to add this data; searc in the internet does give examples of username and password, but seartching on keyfile doesn't show any hits...

What does this do in gsoap, and how to the same in Delphi (2018) / Indy10 ?

Comment: What is "Delphi 2018"? Never heard of it...

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand probably means the 2018 version of Delphi (which would be 10.2 Tokyo Update 3)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed - 10.2 Tokyo..
We found the solution in re-importing the WSDL's into Delphi and use code we already had for accessing certificates.